# stanfordNLP Pipeline - Python

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I was wondering how to actually use the StanfordNLP Pipeline through python using the stanfordnlp library. There doesn't seem to be any clear documentation as to how to actually enter the annotators, their attributes, etc.?

For example, nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline() sets up a new pipeline. Is there a way to specify which annotators it uses?

For example, I want to specify the following commands:

```
-annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,coref,quote -coref.algorithm statistical
```

How would I do that using the stanfordnlp.Pipeline() command?

Answer (score 0):

There are two pipelines:

- the native Python pipeline runs tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse
- the traditional Java pipeline

If you want to use the Java pipeline, you need to use the server.

There is detailed discussion of this here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/corenlp_client.html